# How to iterate down an Array in chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to build an application that takes a text from a website (for the app I'm using gutenburg.org's open ebook catalog) and displays the story in bites of 10 indexes at a time in a div to make the story easier to read for those with ADD. I have a working increment function but I'm stuck as to how to increment back to the previous chunk.

```
HTML:
<input type="text" id="url" style="width: 400px">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get JSON">
<button id="button">Next</button>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<div id="test"></div>
Javscript:
   $(function() {
        $( '#service' ).on( 'change', function(){
            $( '#url' ).val( $( this ).val() );
        });

        //angular.module('exampleApp')
        $( '#url' ).val( $( '#service' ).val() );

        $( '#btn' ).click(function(){
            var url = $( '#url' ).val()

            $.ajax({
              crossOrigin: true,
              proxy: "http://localhost:8888/whorl/proxy.php",
              url: url,
              //dataType: "json", //no need. if you use crossOrigin, the dataType will be override with "json"
              //charset: 'ISO-8859-1', //use it to define the charset of the target url
              context: {},
              success: function(data) {
                  //alert(data);
                  var body = data; 
                  console.log(body.length);
                  //body/data is a string
                  var text = body.split(' ')
                  console.log(text.length);



        var increment = function(array) {
        if (array.chunk < array.length) {
            var chunk =      array.slice(array.chunk,Math.min(array.chunk+array.chunkSize, array.length).join(" ");
            array.chunk += array.chunkSize;
            $( '#test' ).html(chunk);
            console.log(chunk);
        }
    };





        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function() {
          increment(text);

        });
});
  }
        })
        .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            //alert(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#chunk if you don't want to use the dependency, you could at least check the source.

Answer (score 1):

pass an attribute, value would be either INCREMENT or DECREMENT

```
if (value=='increment')    
     array.chunk += array.chunkSize; 
else
     array.chunk -= array.chunkSize;
```

Comment: Like this, within the increment function? When I attempt this it just keeps incrementing up                                                                             if ($(button).attr("value","incr")) { 
     array.chunk += array.chunkSize; 
                          }else{
     array.chunk -= array.chunkSize; 
                         }